# Where to put authentication/authorization in MVP

Tags: authentication, authorization, mvp

My design looks like this:

```
View <-- Presenter --> Services --> Repositories --> Entities
```

Where I should put the authentication/authorization in this design?

I was thinking I could use attributes on the service methods specifying the required permissions/roles, then using an interceptor to enforce them. Would this be a good approach or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

yes this is how it is normally done. if you ever expose services via REST or SOAP you'll have already this stuff covered. placing it in presenter would be wasteful.